# How to add values from different div classes using js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with different `<td>` class names. I need to add/sum each of these for one total value. I can do this easily if they all had the same class name, but I cannot figure how to do it with different classes. So, in the table example below, I need to add .price1 + .price2 + .price3 and have the results display in #result.

HTML:

```
    <table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>Item1</td>
         <td class="price1">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Item2</td>
         <td class="price2">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Item3</td>
         <td class="price3">25</td>
        </tr>         
        <tr class="summary">
         <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td>
         <td id="result" class="totalAmount"></td>
        </tr>                                 
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this selector , make use of wildcards

```
$("[class^=price]")
```

code is

```
var result=0;
$("[class^=price]").each(function(e,i){result+=parseInt(i.innerHTML)});
console.log(result) // u get to see the result in console
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that all your `<td>` html values are numbers, using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var total = 0;  
  total += $('#tableOrderTotal .price1').html();
  total += $('#tableOrderTotal .price2').html();
  total += $('#tableOrderTotal .price3').html();
  $("#result").html(total);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion and more simple, is create an attribute and some with it, something like...

```
<td class="price1" to-sum>5</td>
<td class="price2" to-sum>5</td>
<td class="price3" to-sum>5</td>
```

And then select by attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('td[to-sum]').each(function(item) {
        total += parseFloat($(this).text());
    })

    $("#result").html(total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item1</td>
            <td class="price1" to-sum>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item2</td>
            <td class="price2" to-sum>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item3</td>
            <td class="price3" to-sum>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="summary">
            <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td>
            <td id="result" class="totalAmount"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be just add some data attribute or class, but I assume You can not do that. So it is few possible solution, for example We can do selector by `tr` and get every last `td` in `tr` or do selector by regular expression. Here example code.

```js
//solution with selector by tr
var sum=0;
$('tr:not(.summary)').each(function() {

   
    sum+=parseInt( $(this).find("td").last().text() );
     
});

$("td#result").text(sum);

//second possibile solution is to do regular expression selector 
//( get every element with class starting by "price")
var sum=0;
$('td[class^=price]').each(function() {

   
    sum+=parseInt( $(this).text() );
     
});
$("td#result2").text(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>Item1</td>
         <td class="price1">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Item2</td>
         <td class="price2">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Item3</td>
         <td class="price3">25</td>
        </tr>         
        <tr class="summary">
         <td class="totalOrder">Total:</td>
         <td id="result" class="totalAmount"></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr class="summary">
         <td class="totalOrder">Total second solution:</td>
         <td id="result2" class="totalAmount"></td>
        </tr>                               
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Your 2nd option is almost working - however one of the td classes I am using is populated with from a computed calculated value from a select (dropdown) menu, and this value is not being included in the sum calculation. Basically, when a value from my select menu is selected, I have some js that is multiplying the selected value by a specified number and populating the .price1 td class with this computed value. This value is not being included in the total sum (#result). The others are included just fine, but the calculated value of .price1 is not. Any ideas?

Comment: I am again playing with your option #2 code and I am getting a NaN result when I include my calculated value of .price1. How can I sum my different classes when one more of the classes is populated by a separate js function? The js that calculates the .price1 is working perfectly - it calculates it depending on the user selection from the dropdown - and it populates the .price1 <td> just fine. However, the .price1 will not sum using your supplied code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Code Snippet.

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $('[class^="price"]').each(function(){
            sum = sum + parseInt($(this).html());
        });
        $('[class$="totalAmount"]').html(sum);
    })

</script>
```

It is basically getting the Text inside each `td` whose `class` has starts with prefix `price` and then adds them all.

Finally, It sets the `text` of your `totalAmount` `td` to the sum obtained earlier.

I hope, It will help.